# Removing duplicated rows but keep the ones with a particular value in one column (pandas python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I would like to do the following:

If two rows have exactly the same value in 3 columns ("ID","symbol", and "date") and have either "X" or "T" in one column ("message"), then remove both of these rows. However, if two rows have the same value in the same 3 columns but a value different than "X" or "T" in the other column, then leave intact.

Here is an example of my data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":["AA-1", "AA-1", "C-0" ,"BB-2", "BB-2"], "symbol":["A","A","C","B","B"], "date":["06/24/2014","06/24/2014","06/20/2013","06/25/2014","06/25/2015"], "message": ["T","X","T","",""] })
```

Note that the first two rows have the same value values for the columns "ID","symbol", and "date", and "T" and "X" in the column "message". I would like to remove these two rows.

However, the last two rows have the same value in columns "ID","symbol", and "date", but blank (different than "X" or "T") in the column "message".

I am interested in applying the function to a large dataset with several million rows. So far what I have tried consumes all my memory,

thank you and I appreciate any help,

Comment: Just to clarify- do you want to keep duplicate rows in case there are more than 2?

Comment: I should probably make that more clear in my question. My data comes in pairs. For every "X" row, there is (or at least should be) exactly one "T" row with other columns equal except for the "message" column. In this case, at least if the data was gathered correctly, there should only be pairs of matching observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
vals = ['X', 'T']
pd.concat([df[~df.message.isin(vals)], df[df.message.isin(vals)].loc[~df.duplicated(subset=['ID', 'date', 'symbol'], keep=False), :]])

     ID        date message symbol
3  BB-2  06/25/2014              B
4  BB-2  06/25/2015              B
2   C-0  06/20/2013       T      C
```

It's reasonably fast:

```
%%timeit
pd.concat([df[~df.message.isin(['X', 'T'])], df[df.message.isin(['X', 'T'])].loc[~df.duplicated(subset=['ID', 'date', 'symbol'], keep=False), :]])
100 loops, best of 3: 1.99 ms per loop

%%timeit
df.groupby(['ID','date','symbol']).filter(lambda x: ~x.message.isin(['T','X']).all())
100 loops, best of 3: 2.71 ms per loop
```

The alternative was giving indexing errors.

Comment: There is problem with `If two rows have exactly the same value in...` - your solution filter all duplicates rows, not only with length 2.

Comment: That's right I was just following the headline instruction. Let's see what's required. My answer won't help if the OP wants to keep duplicated rows if there are more than 2.

Comment: The concat function runs significantly faster that the groupby in this case

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) - conditions are - not `2` rows with duplicate values and column `message` in groups [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) have not values `T` or `X`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":["AA-1", "AA-1", "C-0" ,"BB-2", "BB-2"],
                   "symbol":["A","A","C","B","B"],
                   "date":["06/24/2014","06/24/2014","06/20/2013","06/25/2015","06/25/2015"],
                   "message": ["T","X","T","",""] })
print (df) 
     ID        date message symbol
0  AA-1  06/24/2014       T      A
1  AA-1  06/24/2014       X      A
2   C-0  06/20/2013       T      C
3  BB-2  06/25/2015              B
4  BB-2  06/25/2015              B

df1 = df.groupby(['ID','date','symbol']).filter(lambda x: ~((len(x) == 2) & 
                                                          (x.message.isin(['T','X']).all())))
print (df1)
     ID        date message symbol
2   C-0  06/20/2013       T      C
3  BB-2  06/25/2015              B
4  BB-2  06/25/2015              B
```

[Filtration in docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration).

EDIT by [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777662/removing-duplicated-rows-but-keep-the-ones-with-a-particular-value-in-one-column#comment63023864_37777662):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":["AA-1", "AA-1", "C-0", "C-0","BB-2", "BB-2"],
                   "symbol":["A","A","C","C", "B","B"],
                   "date":["06/24/2014","06/24/2014","06/20/2013","06/20/2013","06/25/2015","06/25/2015"], 
                   "message": ["T","X","X","X","",""] })
print (df) 
     ID        date message symbol
0  AA-1  06/24/2014       T      A
1  AA-1  06/24/2014       X      A
2   C-0  06/20/2013       X      C
3   C-0  06/20/2013       X      C
4  BB-2  06/25/2015              B
5  BB-2  06/25/2015              B
```

If need remove values with `X` or `T` in each group - it means it remove double `X` or double `T` too and each `len` of each group is always `2`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['ID','date','symbol']).filter(lambda x: ~x.message.isin(['T','X']).all())
print (df1)
     ID        date message symbol
4  BB-2  06/25/2015              B
5  BB-2  06/25/2015              B
```

If need remove only groups where are values `T` and `X`, you can first [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by `message` and then `filter` by checking if first value is `T` and second `X` in each group. ('T' is first and `X` is second, because sorting):

```
df2 = df.sort_values('message')
        .groupby(['ID','date','symbol'], sort=False)
        .filter(lambda x: ((x.message.iloc[0] != 'T') | (x.message.iloc[1] != 'X')))
print (df2)
     ID        date message symbol
4  BB-2  06/25/2015              B
5  BB-2  06/25/2015              B
2   C-0  06/20/2013       X      C
3   C-0  06/20/2013       X      C
```