# Remove duplicates in one column, in multiple other columns, change row value to max of that column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following format:

```
id  x1 x2 x3 
A   1  0  0
A   0  1  0
A   0  0  0
B   1  0  0
B   0  0  0 
B   0  0  1
```

I would like to "compress" this based on the repeated values in `id`, keeping the `1`'s under the correct column, but in a single row for the `id`. That is, the dataframe should look like this at the end:

```
id  x1 x2 x3 
A   1  1  0
B   1  0  1
```

My actual data set is millions of rows with potentially thousands of columns. I could do this by grouping by rows and looping over columns, but would like to know if there is a more Pythonic/Pandified/memory efficient way of doing this.

I have looked at answers for questions that are concerned with keeping the max (or some other function) of a column, but that goes back to having to loop over all the columns. ([Here is one example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777662/removing-duplicated-rows-but-keep-the-ones-with-a-particular-value-in-one-column))

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the simplest, most efficient way to do this in pandas:

```
In [8]: df.groupby('id').max()
Out[8]: 
    x1  x2  x3
id            
A    1   1   0
B    1   0   1
```

Comment: dangit. Well, now I just feel dumb.